# Protecting against malicious signatures

Tags: gnosis-safe

Is spinning up a local web wallet from here https://github.com/safe-global/safe-wallet-web enough to protect me from dns attacks and things like that?

Signatures are gibberish and you can sign malicious stuff if gnosis web app is compromised. I'm trying to protect myself from this.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you're trying to achieve. Why exactly would you want to run your own web ui for the Safe{Wallet}? What signatures are gibberish? The signatures on transactions? What exactly do you mean by "gibberish"?